# How do I use config file to use tzdata?

Tags: elixir

I am following https://elixirschool.com/en/lessons/basics/date_time#working-with-timezones-4 and I want to use tzdata to follow along with the tutorial.

I am in `~/learning_elixir` and I have a `simple.exs` file along with a `config/config.exs` file in which I have

```
import Config

config :elixir, :time_zone_database, Tzdata.TimeZoneDatabase
```

When I use `iex` and try to follow the tutorial

```
paris_datetime = DateTime.from_naive!(~N[2019-01-01 12:00:00], "Europe/Paris")
#DateTime<2019-01-01 12:00:00+01:00 CET Europe/Paris>
{:ok, ny_datetime} = DateTime.shift_zone(paris_datetime, "America/New_York")
{:ok, #DateTime<2019-01-01 06:00:00-05:00 EST America/New_York>}
ny_datetime
#DateTime<2019-01-01 06:00:00-05:00 EST America/New_York>
```

It doesn't work and I get this error

```
** (ArgumentError) cannot convert ~N[2019-01-01 12:00:00] to datetime, reason: :utc_only_time_zone_database
    (elixir 1.13.4) lib/calendar/datetime.ex:624: DateTime.from_naive!/3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As by the tutorial,

> As we have noted in the previous section, by default *Elixir* does not have any timezone data. To solve this issue, we need to install and set up the [`tzdata`](https://github.com/lau/tzdata) package. After installing it, you should globally configure *Elixir* to use *Tzdata* as timezone database.

Have you installed `tzdata`? How have you done it if you have no `mix` project and just play with stuff from the console? Why would you expect `config/3` would work magically without `mix` project?

That said, to make it work from `iex` session without `mix` project, one should install `tzdata` and set the application environment explicitly.

```elixir
Mix.install([:tzdata])
Application.put_env(:elixir, :time_zone_database, Tzdata.TimeZoneDatabase)

paris_datetime = DateTime.from_naive!(~N[2019-01-01 12:00:00], "Europe/Paris")
#DateTime<2019-01-01 12:00:00+01:00 CET Europe/Paris>
```

Comment: Thanks! super noob here, I get it now

Answer (score 0):

You need to start iex using `iex -S mix`.